# Show top results in my sorting function

Tags: python, function

I have hundreds of lists, below I have provided several examples of these lists.

I have function which sorts lists based on the their contents compared to `ref` list.

```
ABCC = ['TRIM', 'IGL@', 'DOCK', 'SVEP', 'S100', 'EPH', 'KLH', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

ACC = ['GULP', 'PREP', 'FHL', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BEC75 = ['LMNA', 'NHP', 'IDS', 'ATP', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARN = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA']

lists = ([("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)])

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        if matches > 1:
            print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))
```

How can I modify this function so that it shows only top 5 results?

```
sort_by_matches(ref,lists)
sort_by_matches(ACC,lists)
```

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Can you explain what your function is doing? There might be a better way to d oit.

Comment: The function is sorting the hundreds of lists based on their content similarity. The more number of same strings between ref list and any given list, the higher Matching %.

Answer (score 0):

first, your function does not have `return` so it only prints out things without actually returning anything

change `print` to `return`.

```
def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = your_sorted_list
    return lists
```

`sort_by_matches(ref,lists)[:5]` would print the first five items if it is a list.

if you dont mind using/learning pandas, which is a package for data analysis, it has a better way to show dataframe with `df.head(n)` which show the top n items

Comment: `sort_by_matches(ACC,lists)[:5]`

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: you wrap the list into a tuple by having a bracket outside, this is unnecessary since inside are already tuples

Comment: sorry I don't understand.

Comment: `list = [("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)]` is good enough, remove the brucket

Comment: Unfortunately same error.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable